# button resets only the selector but not the data related to the selected option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is a table having a filter from which is possible to select an option of a dropdown menu and the table will show only the data for which `type=selected type`.

there is also a button for resetting the selector to the first option.

the problem that I have is that I can't make these two functionalities run in the same time:

- the **selector to update the data** on the table
- **the reset button to reset the selector and the table to the first option**

this is the selector and button html code:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.type">
    <option value="">all</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>


<div class="btn action-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
    Reset Filters
</div>
```

and the table body:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData | filter: {Type:type} track by $index">
        <td>
            <span>{{rows.Type}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="row in rows.Parameters track by $index">{{rows.Parameters[$index]}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{rows.Name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

in controller it is this:

```
class MyCtrl {
    constructor(...) {
        ....
        this.type = "";

    }

...

    doSomething() {
        this.type = "";
    }
}
```

How it is now, when I click the reset button, it resets the selector to the first option but no matter what I do to the selector the table data remains unchanged.

BUT, if a change the first line of the selector from:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.type">
```

to

```
<select ng-model="type">
```

the selector works well, it updates the table with the data coresponding to the selected option but now the reset button has no effect.

How can I make it to have the both functionalities in the same time?

Comment: Which method do you call on selector change?

Comment: I don't understand. All I call and use is in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing the controller variable in your filter. Change this line:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData | filter: {Type:type} track by $index">
```

to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData | filter: {Type:$ctrl.type} track by $index">
```

It should work as expected then.